# Custom-Settings slow load (ApplicationSettingsBase)

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings, applicationsettingsbase

The first load of Custom-Settings takes around 2 seconds *every time the application is started*.

Is there some way to accelerate it?

(Or is this widely used, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522666/net-applicationsettingsbase-unreliable#comment20249440_14522666), despite the speed penalty.)

**Here's the code:**

```
public class MySettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    public int MyInt
    {
        get { return (int)(this["MyInt"]); }
        set { this["MyInt"] = value; }
    }
}
```

And called so:

```
MySettings s = new MySettings();
int i = s.MyInt;
```

Comment: How are you timing it?

Comment: @ken Breakpoint + F10.

Comment: You may be timing the debugger. Use a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and run the compiled code in a console or forms application.

Comment: @ken Still over 1200 ms in Release mode. And this is a simple case. In the real case - the object is more complex and might take even more time. But in any case - that's too long.